# New to Eclipse + How can I start the project using Eclipe? Package mean?

Tags: eclipse, package

I haven't used Eclipse before.  I just installed Eclipse and JDK.  I found some folders online which included some codes such as factory method (pizzafm), simple factory (pizzaas), abstract factory (pizzaaf)

```
package headfirst.factory.pizzaaf;

package headfirst.factory.pizzafm;

package headfirst.factory.pizzas;
```

Could someone explain those packages above mean?

When I start to create a project using Eclipse tool, what's the project name? (is it headfirst?), package name? (factory?), source folder (is it the folder that I need to put all the .java class in?)

Answer (score 0):

`headfirst.factory` is the package name and `pizzaaf` is the `class` name.

Your project name can be anything you like but when you are creating a java class in that project say `Pizzaaf` then in the package textbox you need to enter `headfirst.factory` as I can see from your question.

[image: New Class]

See in the image I have chosen my project name as `Abc` so when I right click on it and select `New->Class` it shows `Abc/src` meaning my source files `.java` files will be in this folder. 
Now I want to create `Pizzaaf.java` file inside a package `headfirst.factory` so I have written `Pizzaaf` in the "Name" textbox and `headfirst.factory` int the "Package" textbox. Now when you will click "Finish" you `Pizzaaf.java` will be in the hierarchy `Abc\src\headfirst\factory\Pizzaaf.java`.

Hope you will get the understanding.